Can not get visual studio 2022 test explorer to find C++ Google Tests
I'm working with Visual Studio 2022, C++ and want to use the Google Test framework through the test explorer. The tests are building and can run but the test explorer can not find any of my tests.
I'm using the test explorer on a regular basis in c# projects and the NUnit test framework without problems.
Before someone makes a remark and points to another question, I have checked a virtually identical request Visual Studio 2019 Test Explorer did not find c++ google tests but can't use the accepted answer (see below for more details). I also have checked a few other requests.
This is what I have done, step by step.
In the following details are given for the x64 platform. Results for x86 are identical.
I created a test project 'MyTest' using template 'Google Test'.
The content of test.cpp is as follows: (closely following an example I found on the internet.)
#include "pch.h"

static long long Factorial(int n)
{
    if (n < 0) return 0L;
    switch (n)
    {
    case 0: return 1L;
    case 1: return 1L;
    default: return Factorial(n - 1) + Factorial(n - 2); // actually this is Fibonacci, not Factorial.
    }
}

// Tests factorial less than 0.
TEST(FactorialTest, HandlesNegativeInputTest)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(Factorial(-2), 0);
    EXPECT_EQ(Factorial(-1), 0);
}

// Tests factorial of 0.
TEST(FactorialTest, HandlesZeroInputTest)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(Factorial(0), 1);
}

// Tests factorial of positive numbers.
TEST(FactorialTest, HandlesPositiveInputTest)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(Factorial(1), 1);
    EXPECT_EQ(Factorial(2), 2);
    EXPECT_EQ(Factorial(3), 3);
    EXPECT_EQ(Factorial(8), 34);
}

Note: code changed after suggestions made by 3CxEZiVlQ, see remarks below.
Project 'MyTest' is marked as the default project for F5.
The project builds and runs without any problems. From console:
...\sources\x64\Debug>MyTest.exe --gtest_list_tests
Running main() from D:\a\_work\1\s\ThirdParty\googletest\googletest\src\gtest_main.cc
FactorialTest.
  HandlesNegativeInput
  HandlesZeroInput
  HandlesPositiveInput

And from using F5:
Running main() from D:\a\_work\1\s\ThirdParty\googletest\googletest\src\gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 3 tests from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 3 tests from FactorialTest
[ RUN      ] FactorialTest.HandlesNegativeInput
[       OK ] FactorialTest.HandlesNegativeInput (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] FactorialTest.HandlesZeroInput
[       OK ] FactorialTest.HandlesZeroInput (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] FactorialTest.HandlesPositiveInput
[       OK ] FactorialTest.HandlesPositiveInput (0 ms)
[----------] 3 tests from FactorialTest (3 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 3 tests from 1 test case ran. (6 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 3 tests.

...\sources\x64\Debug\MyTest.exe (process 11176) exited with code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .

But using the 'Run all tests' button in the test explorer does not give any result, no tests are identified, no problems are reported. Pushing the 'Run all tests' button:
Build started at 14:57...
1>------ Build started: Project: MyTest, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>pch.cpp
1>test.cpp
1>MyTest.vcxproj -> ...\sources\x64\Debug\MyTest.exe
1>Done building project "MyTest.vcxproj".
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 14:57 and took 06,082 seconds ==========

I have checked identical request Visual Studio 2019 Test Explorer did not find c++ google tests
The accepted answer is using CMake files and some rather specific (and to me obscure) details.
I do not know how to work with CMake and would rather not use it for this particular project, its use would be a 'one of' for me.
There is (for me) no indication that CMake is absolutely essential to get this problem solved.
Followed a remark to the original question about the use of main(...).
Providing an implementation of main(...) does not make any difference.
I have visited the following sited for further information

https://github.com/Microsoft/TestAdapterForGoogleTest?tab=readme-ov-file
https://computingonplains.wordpress.com/google-test-and-visual-studio/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/run-unit-tests-with-test-explorer?view=vs-2022


checked configuration.
Test Adaptor for Google Test is installed and available in Tools->Options->Test Adaptor for Google Test. Left all configuration details in the default settings.
The project is using the "Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn" package.

Marked Tools->Options->Test Adaptor for Google Test->Print Debug Info = true.
This does not give different output and does not generate any new information.

checked manual run.
Can build and run tests on the command line (including with option --gtest_list_tests). Results as expected.

Checking section troubleshooting from https://github.com/Microsoft/TestAdapterForGoogleTest?tab=readme-ov-file



No file '*.exe.is_google_test', added in project and copied to build results but it makes no difference
'Configure a Regex for test discovery at the same place.' but no information on what to add where. I do not know what tho do for it.

I'm stuck, does anybody have some advice on how to get the tests visible in the test explorer?

Test suit name must end with Test. I am not sure if the test explore is able to expand macros.

@3CxEZiVIQ: according to GoogleTest primer it is easy to confuse names, so I'm a bit carefull on this. All names I use, for whatever it is and related to testing end with Test, the project is named MyTest, the primary source file is test.cpp, the test group is called FactorialTest (code borrowed from GoogleTest primer). I think that I've forfilled the requirement to use Test at the end of (some) names. I'm not sure how the test explorer is processing all the items and that is whre the problem is (I think).

TEST(GROUP, HandlesNegativeInput) - direct my eyes to "Test" there. Again, the test explorer might not expand the macro GROUP.

Point taken. I removed GROUP and replaced it with the original text 'FactorialTest' and I appended 'Test' to all names used in the second argument. The project still builds and run with the same results. And unfortunately so is the test explorer in not finding any tests.

Just checked, TEST(FactorialTest, HandlesNegativeInput) works well at me.

Problem solved.
The cause of the Test Explorer in not finding any tests is in the way I have my data organised.
I keep all my data on a network share and use a link to the share so that it appears as drive 'H:'. The actual data in on a NAS.
While discovering tests the Test Explorer skips 'extrenal data' and I have overseen this line :-(
File H:\...\MyTestSolution\sources\MyTest\x64\Debug\MyTest.exe came from another computer and was blocked to help protect this computer.

As a test I copied the project do my local C: drive, unchanged.
Now the Test explorer can find tests.
This changes the question to How can I make Test explorer to accept data from my NAS? but that is a different issue.
Edit: The following command to create a path in a local resource (and opening the solution using that location) seems to circumvent the Test Explorer check.
mklink /D C:\Home \\MyNas\MyHome

Note: This is by no way a general method to make a NAS share look like a local device/directory but it is good enough to fool the Test Explorer at this moment in time.
